# What does the PHP syntax $var1->$var2 mean?

Tags: php, syntax

What is the explanation for the following syntax?

```
$var1->$var2 // Note the second $
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are calling a property on `$var1` that is named the same as the value of `$var2`.

For example:

```
$var2 = "name";

// The following are equivalent
$var1->name;
$var1->$var2;
```

Answer (score 10):

`$var1` is an object.

`$var2` is (possibly) the name of a variable inside `$var1`.

If `$var2="test";` this is evaluated to:

```
$var1->test;
```

You can do this with all sorts of things:

```
$test = array();
$name="test";
print_r($$name); // Prints array();

$test = new stdClass;
$test->hello = "hi";
$name2="hello";
echo $test->$name2; // Echos hi
```

You can even get really fancy:

```
echo $$name->$name2; // Echos hi
```

Comment: What's with the double dollar signs?

Comment: Can you include an example of a get/post with an else?

Comment: @CodyBugstein if `$foo="bar"` and `$bar="biz"` then `$$foo` will return `"biz"` because the double dollar sign will tell the computer to get the variable whose name is the value of `foo`. Basically, in `$$foo`, replace in your head `$foo` with `bar` and you get `$bar`. Note the `$` in `$bar`is the first `$` in `$$foo` which remains after you replaced it in your head. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-dollar-dollar-or-double-dollar-mean-in-php

Answer (score 2):

It means dynamically query a property in an object.

```
class A {
  public $a;
}

// static property access
$ob = new A;
$ob->a = 123;
print_r($ob);

// dynamic property access
$prop = 'a';
$ob->$prop = 345; // effectively $ob->a = 345;
print_r($ob);
```

so `$var1` is an instance of some object, `->` means access to a member of that object and `$var2` contains the name of a property.