# What does $$ (dollar dollar or double dollar) mean in PHP?

Tags: php

Example is a variable declaration within a function:

```
global $$link;
```

What does `$$` mean?

Comment: *(related)* [What does that symbol mean in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

Comment: It's a name-based de-reference. Something like `${$link}` in Bash

Comment: (related)[variable variables with PHP's Superglobal arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58832360/6521116)

Answer (score 227, accepted):

A syntax such as **`$$variable`** is called [**Variable Variable**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

For example, if you consider this portion of code:

```
$real_variable = 'test';
$name = 'real_variable';
echo $$name;
```

You will get the following output:

```
test
```

Here:

- `$real_variable` contains `'test'`
- `$name` contains the name of your variable: `'real_variable'`
- `$$name` mean "*the variable thas has its name contained in `$name`*"

  - Which is `$real_variable`
  - And has the value `'test'`

---

**EDIT after @Jhonny's comment:**

Doing a `$$$`?
Well, the best way to know is to try ;-)

So, let's try this portion of code:

```
$real_variable = 'test';
$name = 'real_variable';
$name_of_name = 'name';

echo $name_of_name . '<br />';
echo $$name_of_name . '<br />';
echo $$$name_of_name . '<br />';
```

And here's the output I get:

```
name
real_variable
test
```

So, I would say that, **yes, you can do `$$$`** ;-)

Comment: While I agree that it can be useful, most of the times it's better to use arrays anyway.

Comment: so is this the same thing as doing ${$value}?

Comment: @Chaim : yes it is ;; except that, in some cases, the `{` and `}` are required *(there's an example in the manual about that)*

Answer (score 25):

The inner $ resolves the a variable to a string, and the outer one resolves a variable by that string.

So, consider this example

```
$inner = "foo";
$outer = "inner";
```

The variable:

```
$$outer
```

would equal the string "foo"

Comment: Even though the accepted anwser is a lot broader (including test cases). This explanation made it clearer for me

Answer (score 14):

It's a [variable's variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

```
<?php
$a = 'hello';
$$a = 'world'; // now makes $hello a variable that holds 'world'
echo "$a ${$a}"; // "hello world"
echo "$a $hello"; // "hello world"
?>
```

Answer (score 8):

It creates a dynamic variable name. E.g.

```
$link = 'foo';
$$link = 'bar';    // -> $foo = 'bar'
echo $foo;
// prints 'bar'
```

(also known as [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php))

Answer (score 4):

I do not want to repeat after others but there is a risk using `$$` :)

```
$a  = '1';
$$a =  2; // $1 = 2 :)
```

So use it with head. :)

Answer (score 3):

It evaluates the contents of one variable as the name of another. Basically it gives you the variable whose name is stored in `$link`.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me (enclose in square brackets):

```
$aInputsAlias = [
        'convocatoria'   => 'even_id',
        'plan'           => 'acev_id',
        'gasto_elegible' => 'nivel1',
        'rubro'          => 'nivel2',
        'grupo'          => 'nivel3',
    ];

    /* Manejo de los filtros */

    foreach(array_keys($aInputsAlias) as $field)
    {
        $key = $aInputsAlias[$field];

        ${$aInputsAlias[$field]} = $this->request->query($field) ? $this->request->query($field) : NULL;
    }
```