# i got this PHP question from my friend about variable dollar sign

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does $$ mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-mean-in-php)

what is the different between $thisvariable and $$thisvariable. as you notice, the first variable has one dollar sign while the second got two dollar signs.

Comment: duplicate of [what does $$ mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-mean-in-php)

Comment: The PHP manual is always a good place to start. :) http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$variable` is a [variable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php) and `$$variable` is a [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php),

```
$my_name = "anthony"; // variable $my_name 
echo $my_name; // outputs "anthony"

$a_var = "my_name"; // assigning literal to variable $a_var
echo $$a_var; // outputs "anthony"
```

It may be a bit confusing, so let's break down that echo call,

```
$($a_var)  
   -> $(my_name) 
       -> $my_name = "anthony"
```

Please note that the above may not be what happens behind the scenes of the PHP interpreter, but it serves strictly as an illustration.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

`$thisvariable` is a [variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.php) named `$thisvariable`:

```
$thisvariable = 'Hello';
print $thisvariable; // prints Hello
```

`$$thisvariable` is a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

```
$thisvariable = 'Hello';
$Hello = 'Greetings';
print $$thisvariable; // prints Greetings ($$thisvariable is equivalent to $Hello)
```

For the most part you should avoid using variable variables. It makes the code harder to understand and debug. When I see it it's a red flag that there's some bad design.