# Why are there two $$ signs infront of variable?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what does $$ mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-mean-in-php)

I recently needed to make a change on a application and came across this `$pageObject->createPageContent($$templateName);`

The method looked like this

```
function createPageContent($page_content_html) {
        $this->page_content = $page_content_html;
    }
```

My question is when I removed the one $ sign infront of the variable I got a different result as with the double $$. Why is there one $ sign extra? What's the purpose for this?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$$` signifies a [**variable variable**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) in PHP.

It's an easy way to reference an already existing variable by a string.

Here's an example:

```
$someVar = 'something';

$varname = 'someVar';

echo $$varname; //something
```

So, in your example, `$templateName` actually references the **name of an already existing variable**, so when you prepend it with another `$`, PHP gets the value out of that variable. This is a very powerful language feature IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

`$$` represents a variable variable.  The result of `$templateName` is used as the variable name you wish to reference.  For further clarity, it can also be written as

```
${$templateName}
```

For example,

```
$templateName = "hello";
$hello = "world";

echo $$templateName;
//-> "world"
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: I hate it when people upvote one answer over the other when they are actually very very similar. You should be getting equal upvotes.

Comment: not to mention that I was already over the rep cap before answering.

Comment: @Jacob: not to worry - if I'm running out of votes I usually go with faster finger first (when the answers are more or less the same), which was you by 25 seconds :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you're using two $$ it means the name of the variable is actually a veriable.

```
$animal = "cow";

$cow = "moo";

echo $$animal;

//Prints 'moo'
```

Answer (score 0):

This way you are able to address variables dynamically.

There is a [perfect description to be found at php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).