# What is $$ in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does $$ mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-mean-in-php)
>   [Double dollar sign php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179489/double-dollar-sign-php)

What is $$ in php. 
This question is asked in a recent interview for a web developer position.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some of us can understand that it would be difficult to know how to search for $$.

Comment: Google "php two dollar signs".

Answer (score 6):

This is a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). They work by using a variable to contain the name of another variable like so:

```
$var = 'test';
$test = 'echod variable';
echo $$var;
// output echod variable
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

> Sometimes it is convenient to be able to have variable variable names.
>   That is, a variable name which can be set and used dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

dynamic variable name,

for example

```
for($i = 0; $i<10; $i++)
{
  $var_name = "d".$i;
  echo $$var_name;
}
```

will echo the variables $d0, $d1, $d2, $d3... $d9

Answer (score 0):

running this code would set $name

```
$value="name";
$$value="testing";
```

in other words, $name is now equal to "testing"