# abstract class and the use of the static keyword

Tags: php, oop

Sorry if the title looks odd, I don't know how to call it. I was inspecting a framework and I wonder how this works?

```
<?php
//namespace and use

abstract class Model {
    //...
    public function __call($method,$params){
        //some stuff
        return static::$$method;
    }
}
```

It's an abstract class, so to what class will static refer to? (considering it's not extending anything) I tried to `var_dump` method but that method is not in that class. And why does it have a double dollar sign.

**EDIT:** Oh it will call the `__callStatic` method. I need pills.

Comment: What you should be Googling is ["PHP late static bindings"](http://www.google.com/search?q=php+late+static+bindings) - and I'll admit it's not obvious unless you already know. To speed things up, here's where that will land you: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: Which framework is doing this? LSB FTW.

Comment: what's LSB? @MikePurcell

Comment: The $$ is the PHP syntax for creating variable variables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179489/double-dollar-sign-php . Usually pretty evil.

Comment: @Barsoom: Late static binding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called "late static binding" and unlike `self`, which always refers to the context ("class"), where it is defined, it refers always to the context it is called on.