# Variable variable with arrays

Tags: php

I'm confused in how to use $$ to use a string as a variable, mainly when it comes to use a string to refer an array index.
Consider the following case:

```
$colors = array(
'r'=>"red",
'b'=>"blue"
);
$vr = "colors[r]"; //I tried even this "color['r']"
echo $$vr; // I tried even this ${$vr}
```

Can anyone tell if it is possible to do the above.
expected o/p is red using "color[r]" as string and then using it as variable.

Comment: Variable variables are more complicated and less powerful then plain arrays / associative arrays. Just don't use them.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179489/double-dollar-sign-php

Comment: Can there be any alternate solution for this other than just using the plain array/associative array

Comment: I believe you should change `$vr = $colors['r'];`, so that `$vr` contains `"red"`. `$$vr` would then evaluate to `$red`.

Comment: Are you using "color[r]", or "colors[r]"?

Comment: Sorry, thats just a typo, I'm using "colors[r]"

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that directly. Consider the following:

```
$varName = array_shift(explode('[', $vr));

foreach($$varName as $key=>$value){
    echo $key.": ".$value."<br />";
}
```

this will print out:

```
r: red
b: blue
```

The variable variable is just the first part (colors). You can't include the key in this.

Comment: the array can be deeper, to next level i.e. it could have been, $colors['r']['shade']. What if its the following case:
$vr = "colors['r']['shade']". Its dynamic and the depth of array can be anything.

Comment: Then you'd have to write your own parser. But before I go deeper into that: What's the goal of this all? Why are you doing what you're doing? ;)