# I'm confused about this php get code

Tags: php

```
$check=$$_GET[u];

if($_GET[user] && $_GET[user]==$check)
```

I don't under stand about `$check=$$_GET[u]`;
Why that used double `$` ??
so what is value of `$check` u guess?

Comment: [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) See the **big red warning** at the bottom of the page

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179489/double-dollar-sign-php

Comment: suppose $_GET['u'] value is xxx;then $check value is equal to $xxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double $ makes a variable with a name equal to the value of the original variable. 
Example

$name = "steve";

$$name = "jobs";

print ($steve);
// The output is: jobs

What we've done is that we made a new variable, and the new variables name was the value of $name. We assigned "jobs" to the variable by the name of $name's value.

Answer (score 0):

It takes the value of one variable and treats it as name of second variable.

[Variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) This can help you in understanding it with an example.