# difference between call by value and call by reference in php and also $$ means?

Tags: php

(1) I want to know what is the difference between call by value and call by reference in `php`. PHP works on call by value or call by reference?

(2) And also i  want to know that do you mean by $$ sign in php

For example:-

```
$a = 'name';
$$a = "Paul";
echo $name; 

output is Paul
```

As above example what do u mean by $$ on PHP.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php and http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+difference+call+by+reference+value

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`$$a = b;` in PHP means "take the value of `$a`, and set the variable whose *name* is that value to equal `b`".

In other words:

```
$foo = "bar";
$$foo = "baz";
echo $bar; // outputs 'baz'
```

But yeah, take a look at the [PHP symbol reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php).

As for call by value/reference - the primary difference between the two is whether or not you're able to modify the original items that were used to call the function. See:

```
function increment_value($y) {
    $y++;
    echo $y;
}

function increment_reference(&$y) {
    $y++;
    echo $y;
}

$x = 1;
increment_value($x); // prints '2'
echo $x; // prints '1'
increment_reference($x); // prints '2'
echo $x; // prints '2'
```

Notice how the value of `$x` isn't changed by `increment_value()`, but *is* changed by `increment_reference()`.

As demonstrated here, whether call-by-value or call-by-reference is used depends on the definition of the function being called; the default when declaring your own functions is call-by-value (but you can specify call-by-reference via the `&` sigil).

Comment: )if both are same then kkk problem solved –difference between call by value and call by reference in php

Comment: @poter - Both. Notice how the example demonstrates both.

Comment: (P.S. If this is homework, you might want to tag it as such...)

Answer (score 8):

Let's define a function:

```
function f($a) {
  $a++;
  echo "inside function: " . $a;
}
```

Now let's try calling it by value(normally we do this):

```
$x = 1;
f($x);
echo "outside function: " . $x;

//inside function: 2
//outside function: 1
```

Now let's re-define the function to pass variable by reference:

```
function f(&$a) {
  $a++;
  echo "inside function: " . $a;
}
```

and calling it again.

```
$x = 1;
f($x);
echo "outside function: " . $x;

//inside function: 2
//outside function: 2
```

You can pass a variable by reference to a function so the function can modify the variable.
More info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php).

Answer (score 1):

**Call by value**: *Passing the variable value directly and it will not affect any global variable.*

**Call by reference**: *Passing the address of a variable and it will affect the variabl*e.

Answer (score 0):

It means $($a), so its the same as $name (Since $a = 'name'). More explanation here [What does $$ (dollar dollar or double dollar) mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-mean-in-php)

Comment: ) if both are same then kkk problem solved –difference between call by value and call by reference in php

Answer (score 0):

Call by value means passing the value directly to a function. The called function uses the value in a local variable; any changes to it do not affect the source variable.

Call by reference means passing the address of a variable where the actual value is stored. The called function uses the value stored in the passed address; any changes to it do affect the source variable.