# php $$ operator

Tags: php, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does $$ mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-mean-in-php)

I can't find documentation for this anywhere. You'd think it would be easy!

I came across this piece of code when reading through a webmail client framework (favourite pass time hobby) and i dont know what $$ means...

```
if (isset($_POST)){
while ( list($var, $val) = each($_POST) ) $$var = input_filter($var,$val);
}
```

Could somebody also explain basically what this does?

My interpretation is

```
if post is set
    loop until end of $_POST
        initialise each $_POST as a variable,
        filter variables
    end loop
end if
```

Comment: Don't do this. Instead do this: foreach($_POST as $key=>$val){ // blah}

Answer (score 5):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 1):

it's basically mimicing "register globals" for POST.  $$var means take whatever $var evaluates to (it's a string) and make a variable of that name.  So if $var is "email" then $$var is the same as $email.