# How to access php variable using concatenation

Tags: php

I want to access a variable that is either called `$item1`, `$item2` or `$item3`.

I want to access this variable inside a for loop where `$i` is `++` every time.  using `$item.$i` or something similar.  However using  that code means that I am trying to join the contents of two variables, and there is no variable called $item.

Comment: Why don't you use an array of values?

Comment: You can use the double $ symbol. This is expanded upon here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-mean-in-php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @FelixKling thanks, I'm looking into doing that now.  You see $item1, 2 and 3 are already arrays, so it would need to be a multidimensional array

Comment: How to write unmaintable code.

Comment: Using multidimensional arrays is totally normal ;) Variable variables is really a bad and inflexible approach.

Comment: Just because you can, doesnt mean you should. try to avoid variable variables if possible for readability's sake.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks.  Its good for me to learn, I don't know unless someone tells me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Arrays: A Better Method

While PHP does permit you to build dynamic variable names from various other values, you probably shouldn't in this case. It seems to me that an array would be more appropriate for you:

```
$items = array( 0, 12, 34 );
```

You could then access each value individually:

```
echo $items[0]; // 0
echo $items[1]; // 12
```

Or loop over the entire set:

```
foreach ( $items as $number ) {
  echo $number; // 1st: 0, 2nd: 12, 3rd: 34
}
```

#### Merging Multiple Arrays

You indicated in the comments on the OP that `$item1` through `$item3` are already arrays. You could merge them all together into one array if you like with `array_merge()`, demonstrated below:

```
$item1 = array( 1, 2 );
$item2 = array( 3, 4 );
$item3 = array( 5, 6 );

$newAr = array_merge( $item1, $item2, $item3 );

print_r( $newAr );
```

Which outputs:

```
Array
(
  [0] => 1
  [1] => 2
  [2] => 3
  [3] => 4
  [4] => 5
  [5] => 6
)
```

#### If You Must: Dynamic Variable Names

For completeness, if you were to solve your problem by dynamically constructing variable names, you could do the following:

```
$item1 = 12;
$item2 = 23;
$item3 = 42;

for ( $i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++ ) {
  echo ${"item".$i} . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: array_merge, didn't know about that one thanks

Comment: With array_merge be careful of key collisions (for string keys). see: php.net/array_merge

Answer (score 2):

build  the variable name you want to access into another variable then use the [variable variable syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
<?php
   $item1 = 'a';
   $item2 = 'b';
   $item3 = 'c';

   for ($i = 1; $i<=3; $i++) {
       $varname = 'item' . $i;
       echo $$varname;
   }
?>
```

output:

> abc

Note there are other ways to do this, see the manual.

Comment: Finally something approaching a correct answer.

Comment: Just noticed this answer after I posted mine. Eerie how we thought of the same variable values.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i =1;$i<4;$i++){
    $var = 'item'.$i;
    echo $$var;
}
```

Here you are using the the double $ to create a [variable variable](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: Too many `$`s (and I'm not talking about the double one ;-) )

Comment: @DaveRandom it's kinda hard not to use $ in php

Comment: Run this code and you will find it does not work. Look at the line where you assign a value to `$var`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `${'item'.$i}`
If `$i == 1`, then you will access `$item1`.

But it's better to use arrays in your case.

Comment: thanks, I'm looking into doing that now.  You see $item1, 2 and 3 are already arrays, so it would need to be a multidimensional array

Answer (score 0):

Can you use an array instead of individual variables? then you can reference array elements by index value based in `i`.

```
$items = array();

$i = 1;
$items[$i] = "foo";

$i++;
$items[$i] = "bah";

echo $items[1], $items[2];     // gives "foobah"
```

Comment: You seem to be in Javascript mode, `i` think...

Comment: D'oh! thanks Dave. Who's says polyglot is the way forward?

Answer (score 0):

It's a little late, and the accepted answer is the proper way to do this, but PHP does allow you to access variable variable names in the way OP describes:

```
<?php
$item1 = 'a';
$item2 = 'b';
$item3 = 'c';
for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++)
    echo ${"item$i"}; //Outputs: abc
?>
```