# What is the difference between $a and $$a in php?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does $$ mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-mean-in-php)

I am new to PHP and I don't know what the difference between `$a` and `$$a` is.

Comment: what is the problem in my question? why people making -1??

Comment: Because it's a duplicate and this question has been answered very well in an other thread. Make a search before asking net time.

Comment: @j0k: in all fairness, $$ is a difficult term to search for. However, the criteria for a down vote should be *"does not show research effort; is unclear or not useful"*. I down voted because the question shows no research effort.

Comment: i am search it on the google same like i am asked but i am not get it properly then after i am asking it here...and sorry for the my question duplication

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If `$a = 'b'` then `$$a` is `$b`.

This is a variable variable. They are evil. Use arrays instead (which do the same thing, but more maintainably and with the ability to use array functions on them).

Comment: @DhruvThakkar — There are seven explanations here, and a further six beyond the duplicate link, already. If you don't understand any of them then I don't see how I can explain it in a way that you do understand.

Answer (score 27):

`$a` represents a variable

`$$a` represents a variable with the content of `$a`

example:

```
$test = "hello world";
$a = "test";
echo $$a;
```

output will be `hello world`

Answer (score 6):

$variable is a normal variable
$$variable takes the value of a variable and treats that as the name of a variable

eg:

```
$var = 'welcome';
echo $var //prints welcome

$$var = 'to stackoverflow';

echo "$var ${$var}"; //prints welcome to stackoverflow
echo "$var $welcome"; //prints welcome to stackoverflow
```

Answer (score 5):

Double dollar is a powerful way to programmatically create variables and assign values them.

E.g:

```
<?php

$a = “amount”;
$$a =1000;
echo $amount; //echo’s 1000 on screen

?>
```

In the example above, you can see that the variable $a stores the value “amount”. The moment you use a double dollar sign ($$) you are indirectly referencing to the value of $a i.e. amount.

So, with this like $$a = 1000; the variable $amount gets created and I assign the value 1000 to $amount. This way you can programmatically create variables and assign values to them.

Comment: just like a gun is a powerful way of shooting yourself in the foot...

Answer (score 4):

`$a` is the contents of the variable `a`, `$$a` is the contents of the variable *named* in `$a`.

Don't use this syntax in your own code.

Answer (score 3):

`$$a` is a variable which name is in `$a`

Assuming `$a = "foo";`, `$$a` will be same as `$foo`

Answer (score 2):

In PHP each variable starts with an $.

So for example you have the variable `$a = 'var'`;

So `$$a == $var`

This new variable will have the "content" of the other variable as name.