# PHP - Another way to store $_POST Data?

Tags: php

I am trying to store $_POST data that is send from a form. I currently have the following:

> ```
>    for($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++){
>           $f.$x = $_POST['add'.$x];
>     }
> ```

I am trying to make f1 store the $_POST data of field add1.

Is there another way of doing the same function? This doesn't seem to work and it takes up all my CPU usage on my hosting service.

Thanks

Comment: The manual for variable variables is here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: what is this? `$f.$x`? i think you might want to do it with `$name='f'.$x; $$name=$_POST['add'.$x];`

Comment: Why do you need local variables for `$_POST` inputs? Just access them via the `$_POST` superglobal.  Also if you make the form name attrs into an array, they'll arrive in `$_POST` as an array. `<input name='add[0]' />``<input name='add[1]' />`

Comment: What fields do you have in you're form? Do you want to store it in a Database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does $$ mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to create N variables (with the incorrect syntax). Instead, you should use an array:

```
$add_data = array();
for($x = 0; $x <= $count; $x++) {
    $add_data['add'.$x] = $_POST['add'.$x];
}
```

Now all of the elements are present in the `$add_data` array.

Note that the "correct" syntax for what you were originally trying to accomplish is:

```
    ${'f' . $x} =  $_POST['add'.$x];
```

This is called [variable variables](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), and is usually unnecessary.

However, a better approach would be to use arrays to specify the name attributes of your form elements:

```
<input name="add[]" type="text" />
<input name="add[]" type="text" />
```

Then, you can pull `$_POST['add']`, and it will already be an array with all of the `add` elements.

Comment: Looks like we are on the same page :)

Comment: An excellent answer. +1 from me, and my answer is now deleted as it has been vastly outshone by this :)