# Is there a way to show unknown name and value variable in php code?

Tags: php, security, zend-guard

I have a file1.php with a variable. The variable name is unknown.
file1.php is encrypted with ZendGuard 5. So i can not view code.
In file1.php is include file2.php. I dont know place where file2.php is included, because file1.php is encrypted. Is there a way to show unknown name variable in php code?

Example:

file1.php (it will be encrypted with ZendGuard 5)

```
$my_secret_variable='Hi stackoverflow!';
$my_other_secret_variable_SOME_RANDOM_A4Nf8d3ET='Hi stack!';
include ('file2.php');
```

file2.php (not encrypted)
Lets try to guess name and value of secret variable.

```
//first attempt
echo'$my_secret';
//second attempt
echo'$my_secret_var';
//etc
```

Is there a way to show unknown name and value variable in php code?

Comment: I'm not really sure of what you're trying to do, but I think the `$$` in php might help? [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-mean-in-php)

Comment: why you quote variable name in `echo()`? (Not to mention you are actually doing this wrong with single quote)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using [get_defined_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-vars.php):

```
$all = get_defined_vars();

print_r($all);
```

Comment: Khalid Dabjan, i try to hide name and value of my "secret" variable in php code.