# Trying to get variable insisde variable

Tags: php

I"m trying to ask if $value1 is 1

```
$value1 = 1;
$num = 1;

if ($['value'] . $num == 1) {
echo 'good';
} else {
echo 'bad';
}
```

Comment: What you need in dupe is __variable variables__.

Comment: Use `$$` syntax (variable variables). Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d6250ffb54c22a5f500cacc228ce47275971cb1a . Here's some more explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715654/what-does-dollar-dollar-or-double-dollar-mean-in-php