# Use a user-defined variable to dynamically name second database to JOIN tables with that second database

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I need to `JOIN` two different databases which I've already accomplished *statically* for testing purposes only.

1. The first database is already defined in the connection itself.
2. The second database must be dynamically derived from information within the first database that *must first be defined in a user-defined variable*. To keep things simple I will simply refer to the second database name as `example2`.
3. Statically defining the second database name works and all the `JOIN`ed data is successfully pulled *however* with my current comprehension if I did this on a live (or "production") server I'd have to run two separate queries on the same connection with some PHP code in between those two queries.
4. I can not define the second database name without running a second query and the point is to avoid making multiple connections to the SQL server when I know there is a way to do it in a single query (if we do not count setting a user-defined variable a query).

Here is a static demonstration of what worked for me:

```
SELECT * FROM example1 AS e1 
INNER JOIN example2.accounts AS e2a ON (e2a.id = e1.accounts_id);
```

However the following does not work:

```
SET @db = 'example2';
SELECT * FROM example1 AS e1 
INNER JOIN @db.accounts AS e2a ON (e2a.id = e1.accounts_id);
```

How can I set and use a user-defined variable to *dynamically* define the second database's name and use it to dynamically `JOIN` the tables between the two databases?

- All data is properly stored/formatted/etc.
- I already have the user-defined variable working, I need help implementing it on the database-to-database JOIN.
- This sort of relates to the fact that PHP has [variable variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2715671/606371).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL you can use [Prepared Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html) like

```
SET @db = 'example2';
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM example1 AS e1 
                   INNER JOIN ', @db , 
                   '.accounts AS e2a ON e2a.id = e1.accounts_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Better to send one command instead of three commands: ```EXECUTE IMMEDIATE``` (MariaDB > 10.2.3)

Comment: I got it working and I appreciate the extra tidbits (`PREPARE`, `EXECUTE` and `DEALLOCATE`) in an example that isn't convoluted.

Comment: @GeorgRichter Could you please clarify what would `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` replace in M's answer? I'm always for better performance if the reliability remains the same.

Comment: @GeorgRichter Nevermind, the manual actually addresses a real world scenario for once: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/execute-immediate/.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid unnecessary round trips between client and server in 1st answer, here is a 2 liner:

```
SET @db = 'example2';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE CONCAT('SELECT * FROM example1 AS e1 INNER JOIN ', @db , '.accounts AS e2a ON e2a.id = e1.accounts_id');
```

Comment: Thank you, I was already hard at work adapting what I got to work. I've documented *both* in my reference.