# What does operator -> mean in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicates:** 
>   [What does the PHP syntax $var1->$var2 mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316370) 
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139)

I'm looking at a PHP framework's code, and now and then the symbols "->" appear... for example:

```
$controller->permissionCheck($ret);
```

What does "->" stand for and what is used for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your example, `$controller` is a PHP object created somewhere, and permissionCheck is a function defined in that object that is being called with the variable `$ret` being passed to it. Check this: *[Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)*.

Comment: so I'm setting a value to permissionCheck($ret) that is given by $controller ?

so, basically, it's a more elaborated way to assign a value to permissionCheck($ret) ?

Comment: Possibly, but not necessarily.  Controller is an object, and contained within it is a function called permission check. That function could contain a dozen calls to a database that are also in that object , or a call to an opened API. So, in short, you're not assigning a value to anything - you are passing a value to a function.

Answer (score 1):

It's used to address a function or property of a class.
In this case a function of the controller class seems to be called.

Answer (score 1):

Operator `->` is for access to the non-static members of `$controller` object. In your case, the member is the function `permissionCheck`.